# Come out of current debug in intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I am debugging my java code using intellij-idea.
Is there any way so that after reaching at particular line of code I can come out debug and skip other lines of codes ? (Also my current remote debug connection shouldn't be suspended)
F8 is helping out as its going for next frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any breakpoints after a particular code line of yours and use the button "Resume Program"(F9) in Debug window in order to execute the command till the very end.

"View Breakpoints..."(Shift+Ctrl+F8) in that very window is helpful for finding all breakpoints and disabling them.